# Jenkins Bitbuket team/Project or Multibranch Pipeline project copy artifacts from another project not working , as what should be a project name ?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am using bitbucket team project ( Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin), 
I have configured team project with my bitbucket username, I twas taking all repo from the bitbucket with branch in jenkins projects

Now I need to copy artifacts from one project to another project but when I have used copy artifacts from another project spinet generate I have tried to given the project name but it was not working ,

For example I have two repo in bitbucket project with branch each

Then I have created bitbucket team project see following image

[image]

This was dynamically created from the bitbucket team project with repo form the bit bucket

In all project there is branch , see attached screenshot 
1) jenkinsdemoproject
[image]

2) marcurialproject
[image]

- I have written script in jenkinsdemoproject project which will create archive
- I need to copy that artifacts to marcurialproject project

but When I have used copy artifacts from another project jenkin plugin and added project name it was not copying artifacts , as project was dynamically created by bitbucket team/project ( Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin). Does any one have idea how to use copy artifacts for this plugin for multi branch pipeline project?? Please provide me your suggestion

Thanks 
Pratik

Answer (score 2):

Install Copy Artifact Plugin, it should work. The call must be something like this:

```
step([$class: 'CopyArtifact', filter: "artifactName", projectName: "JobName")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that setup will work similar as the multi-branch pipeline job.
That means the job name will include the parent job in which the auto-generated jobs exists.

For example, a multi-branch pipeline job called pipeline, with a branch develop will result in a job name "pipeline/branch/develop".

And if your branch contains a slash, for example "feature/some-feature" the / gets encoded to %252F. So the job name will then be "pipeline/branch/feature%252Fsome-feature".

Comment: I'm afraid the %252F trick does not work for me :-( . Any other suggestion to copy artifacts from multbranch projects with a / (slash) in the branch name is very welcome.